# how to generate gaussian distributed noise based on a data set including cartisian coordinates in python

Tags: python, gaussian

I am looking for any script (preferably Python) to generate Gaussian distributed noise. I have an 3D array including the x,y and z coordinates of a data set in 3D space. Now, I want to generate gaussian noise from this data set. I know that I can generate points with "random.gauss(mu, sigma) function"  but I dont know how can I do it for 3D data? Do I have to do it for each direction? if so, at the end, how I have to correlate them? I am really thankful for any help or hint!!

Thank You

Comment: what do you mean by "generate gaussian noise from this data set"? It sounds like you mean errors on the 3-d positions. Do you know the variance in each direction? Or is it isotropic? What sort of correlations do you want?

Comment: I have an array representing the coordinates of some points in the surface of one cylinder. I want to generate some noise for each point. It is a kind of simulation of optic environmet. So, I have to assume, I have noise for each point. yes, the variance value is given. But no matter they have different variances in each direction or the same. To make it easy we can assume it is isotropic.

Comment: About Correlation, Just I am asking. I dont know even how to generate the noise points in 3D. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is kind of ambiguous. But let's assume that what you have is an `Nx3` array of positions in cartesian (x,y,z) coordinates, and you want to add an error to those positions.

You can use numpy, and in particular [`numpy.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=None)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html). You want to generate a `size=(n,3)` array of "errors", and add them to your position array.

If you want isotropic errors, then you want ⟨|δr|²⟩ = ⟨σ²⟩ = ⟨σ_x² + σ_y² + σ_z²⟩ = 3⟨σ_1²⟩, so the one-dimensional variance is (1/3) the three-dimensional variance, which in turn means that the scale parameter is 1/sqrt(3) the 3D sigma.

Hence you want:

```
noise_plus_signal = signal_in + \
      numpy.random.normal(scale=sigma/numpy.sqrt(3.0), size=(n,3))
```

Or, I've completely misunderstood your question.

Updates:

- if the data are in spherical coordinates, it's probably easiest to convert to and from cartesian and use the algorithm as above
- if you want a different sigma for each point, you can multiply the entire array of random variates (which, if you do it as above, is the same size as your array of points), by another array [using the rules of numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html). In particular, if your array has shape (n,3), you can use `numpy.random.normal(scale=1,size=(n,3))*sigma_array` where `sigma_array` has size `(n)` so that each point gets its own variance, but the `(x,y,z)` coordinates all get the same variance for a given point.

Comment: Many thanks. How about the mean of coordinates? Is there any relationship between mean of x, y, z directions? Or there is no need to specify mean of positions..

Comment: The mean is the signal_in, since the normal variates created by the second term have zero mean.

Comment: When I generate the errors, how can I get their directions? Do I have to use spherical coordinates?

Comment: The algorithm as I presented assumed cartesian coordinates and adds the errors to each, separately.

Comment: By using numpy.random.normal I am creating only some random data. But how can I specify them for each point with specific distance

Comment: See my updated response. Also consider accepting and/or up-voting my answer!